# Joomla - Detect if article is with featured state

Tags: joomla

How can i add custom class="featured" into html\com_content\category\blog_item.php if that rendered article is featured too?

Is there a line of code that can determines if the article is featured?

Thanks!

Comment: Put the answer as an 'answer' and then accept it.

Comment: I second that, please write your answer in the answer box at the bottom of this page (you might need to wait a while though before it will accept it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i`ve got it!

Into html\com_content\category\blog.php

Paste this lines on line 79

```
 <?php 
    $featuredclass = '';
    $item = &$item;
    if ($item->featured == 1) {
        $featuredclass = 'featured';
    } 
?>
```

And add

```
<?php echo $featuredclass;?>
```

on line 86

```
<div class="items-row cols-<?php echo (int) $this->columns;?> <?php echo 'row-'.$row ; ?>">
```

So it looks like this:

```
<?php 
    $featuredclass = '';
    $item = &$item;
    if ($item->featured == 1) {
        $featuredclass = 'featured';
    } 
?>
<div class=" <?php echo $featuredclass;?> items-row cols-<?php echo (int) $this->columns;?>
<?php echo 'row-'.$row ; ?>">
```

Special thanks to [Bojcheski](http://www.facebook.com/bojceski)